# Detecting when the desktop in Windows 8.x is snapped in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a windowless, chromeless WPF application that sits maximized over the desktop. When the desktop gets snapped, my application gets cut off. Likewise, when my application starts in a snapped desktop, it steals focus of the entire monitor.

I need to update my visible elements so that they are no longer cut off by the Windows 8.x snap. Is there an event or api that will let my code react to this change?

Comment: How do you "snap" a desktop?  There are no notifications for Aero Snap, doesn't sound like it.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not talking about aero snap, but the kind of snapping that you can do with a metro app. You can snap the desktop left or right in the same manner.

Comment: The SizeChanged event of the "MainWindow" will fire if the desktop is snapped AND the window changes size. If the height and width are static then the event will not fire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the [SizeChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.FrameworkElement.SizeChanged);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) event of your "MainWindow". This event will fire whenever the user changes the size or the size is changed due to a modern app snapping. The event will not fire if you are setting the width and height to be static.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
}

private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs     sizeChangedEventArgs)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sizeChangedEventArgs.NewSize);            
}
```

Comment: The part I was missing was having the height and width manually set. Setting the window to maximized in conjunction with your answer solved the problem!